# returning a function call instead of a HTTP response in a view

Tags: django, django-views

I don't think I've seen anything that says you're not allowed to do this (or that your are), but is there any reason you shouldn't? It seems to work fine.

```
def get_page(request, topic_slug = 'home', tag_slug = None, form = None):

    #...

    if form is None:
        form = CommentForm()
    d = {'topic':topic, 'topics':topics, 'tags':tags, 'comments':comments, 'form':form}

    d.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('page.html', d)

def save_comment(request, topic_slug):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            #...save
        else:
            kwargs = {'topic_slug':topic_slug}
            kwargs['form'] =form
            return get_page(request, **kwargs) #<-------------- this

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('get_page', kwargs = {'topic_slug':topic_slug}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render_to_response` is just a shortcut. Result of calling it is still `HttpResponse`'s instance.

As a proof, see `render_to_response()`'s declaration in source of Django:

```py
def render_to_response(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns a HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
    django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
    """
    httpresponse_kwargs = {'mimetype': kwargs.pop('mimetype', None)}
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
        **httpresponse_kwargs)
```

Pretty self-explanatory.

By writing this:

```
return get_page(request, **kwargs)
```

you actually do something like:

```
return render_to_response(request, kwargs)
```

(but with slightly altered `kwargs` argument).

Comment: @dishboggett: In such case you return anything the view returns when called like that. View is just a function and if you call it, you get its result.

Comment: hm maybe I'm missunderstanding. I tried `return render_to_response(get_page(request, **kwargs))` but it threw a `TemplateDoesNotExist`

Comment: @dishboggett: You are right, you are misunderstanding. By doing `return render_to_response(get_page(request, **kwargs))` you actually do something similar to `return render_to_response(render_to_response(request, kwargs))` (with slight difference, as I mentioned in answer). I strongly suggest you should read some basic tutorial about how functions work. Maybe this could help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(computer_science). The issue is not Django-relevant, not even Python-relevant. This is not even about [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).